# Why does Heroku deny access to /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr?

Tags: heroku

I'd like to configure an application to write logs to /dev/stdout so they end up in Heroku's logplex.  However I get Permission Denied trying to write to /dev/stdout.

I'm not looking for workarounds. I can cook those up aplenty. I'd really just like to know why Heroku denies opening and writing to /dev/stdout, if anybody has insight into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the Permission Denied error is that the `/dev/stdout` symlink dangles rather than terminating in an allocated pseudo tty in `/dev/pts`:

```
~ $ ls -l /dev/stdout /proc/self/fd/1 /dev/pts/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 2014-03-29 17:21 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 u59417 59417 64 2014-03-29 17:25 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/0
ls: cannot access /dev/pts/0: No such file or directory
```

Since the dangling symlink terminates in a directory (`/dev/pts`) to which the user doesn't have write permission, the OS denies creating the non-existent `/dev/pts/0`

Regarding why `/dev/pts/0` doesn't exist: Heroku's virtualization is based on LXC (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#technologies). This doesn't preclude pseudo tty allocation but in this case the pseudo tty is probably allocated in the host OS, and the guest container isn't inheriting it in `/dev/pts` (whether intentionally or inadvertently, which would be a related question).

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is running Ubuntu. Ubuntu blocks access to /dev/stdout, etc., by default (apparmor). Heroku encourages you to write to STDOUT / STDERR directly with your application stream, as opposed to manually writing to the STDOUT streams in /dev.

UPDATE: This is incorrect -- @Aron Griffis got it right above -- thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't block access to `/dev/stdout` normally. The AppArmor policy only blocks it for a different user that has inherited the standard file descriptors from a parent process, for example using `su`.  In any case, this doesn't apply because the issue in the Heroku container is a dangling symlink (see my answer above)

Comment: Thank you! I've amended my answer to point to yours -- sorry about that! I was going off memory, should have looked.